# Can we integrate from $0$ to $x$ / $t$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I want to find all the solutions of the following problem:

$$w_x(x,t)=3x^2t+t, x,t \in \mathbb{R}\\w_t(x,t)=x^3+x, x, t \in \mathbb{R}$$

I have tried the following:

$$w_x(x,t)=3x^2t+t \Rightarrow \int_0^x w_{s}(s,t)ds=\int_0^x (3s^2t+t)ds \\ \Rightarrow w(x,t)-w(0,t)=3t \frac{x^3}{3}+tx=tx^3+tx \\ \Rightarrow w(x,t)=tx^3+tx+w(0,t) $$

$$w_t(x,t)=x^3+x+w_t(0,t)=x^3+x \Rightarrow w_t(0,t)=0 \Rightarrow \int_0^t w_{\tau}(0, \tau) d \tau=0 \\ \Rightarrow w(0,t)-w(0,0)=0 \Rightarrow w(0,t)=w(0,0)$$

So $w(x,t)=tx^3+tx+w(0,0), x \in \mathbb{R}, t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Is that what I have tried right? Or can't we integrate from $0$ to $x$ and from $0$ to $t$, because of the fact that $x, t \in (-\infty,+\infty)?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly fine. The full solution space is $w(x,t) = (x^3+x)t + C$. Recall that FTC gives us for $w\in C^1(\mathbb R^2)$
$$w(x,t) = w(x_0,t) + \int_{x_0}^x w_x(y,t) \ \mathrm dy = w(x,t_0) + \int_{t_0}^t w_t(x,s)\ \mathrm ds$$
The first equation thus gives us
$$w(x,t) = w(0,t) + \int_0^x 3y^2t + t \ \mathrm dy = (x^3 + x)t + w(0,t) \\
w(x,t) = w(x,0) + \int_0^t x^3 + x \ \mathrm ds = (x^3+x)t + w(x,0)$$
Simultaneously solving these yields
$$w(x,t) = (x^3+x)t + w(0,0) = (x^3+x)t + C$$

Comment: So if we have for example $w_x=4x^2t+t, x, t \in \mathbb{R}\\w_t=x^3+x, x ,t \in \mathbb{R}$ and we want to show that the problem has no solution, could we do it as follows? $$$$
$w(x,t)=w(0,t)+ \int_0^x (4y^2t+t)dy=4\frac{x^3}{3}t+tx+w(0,t) \\ w(x,t)=w(x,0)+\int_0^t (x^3+x)ds=(x^3+x)t+w(x,0)$

So, $4\frac{x^3}{3}t+tx+w(0,t)=(x^3+x)t+w(x,0)\Rightarrow \frac{x^3}{3}t=w(x,0)-w(0,t)$


But how can we find a contradiction?

Comment: Compare coefficients. The statement must hold for all $x,t$. This allows you to eliminate $w(0,t)$ and $w(x,0)$ as constants.

Comment: So you mean that we can say the following? 
$$$$
For $t=0$: $0=w(x,0)-w(0,0) \Rightarrow w(x,0)=w(0,0)$
$$$$
For $x=0$: $0=w(0,0)-w(0,t) \Rightarrow w(0,t)=w(0,0)$
So we have that:
$$\frac{x^3}{3}t=w(x,0)-w(0,t)=0 \Rightarrow x=0 \text{ or } t=0$$
Contradiction since $x,t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes, that's fine. You can leave out the last $\Rightarrow$ though, $\frac13 x^3t \not\equiv 0$ is pretty obvious.

Comment: For the problem of my initial post, couldn't we just say that $u(0,t)=u(x,0)$ and thus it has to hold that $u(0,t)=u(x,0)=C$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Since $w$ is a function w.r.t. $x,t$, integrate the first equation shows

$$w = \int 3x^2t+t dx = x^3t +xt + f(t)$$

since $f(t)$ is treated as a constant when taking partial derivative w.r.t. $x$.

Then you take partial derivative w.r.t $t$ to see what $f$ is

$$w_t = x^3 + x +f'(t)$$

Therefore $f'(t)=0$, so $f = c$.